# How do find /path/to/artisan ?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Trying to Scheduling Artisan Commands

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Can someone please show me how do I know the `/path/to/artisan` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`artisan` is in your Laravel project root. So, if your project path looks like `/home/laravel-proj/` use this:

```
* * * * * php /home/laravel-proj/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Please read an explanation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/what-does-dev-null-21-mean-in-this-article-of-crontab-basics

Answer (score 4):

extending the answer given by @Alexy Mezenin , to get current working directory on ubuntu use **pwd** command.

For windows user it may be **cd**

So if you have a project in **desktop/blog**.
go to the **blog** directory and run **`pwd`** command and you'll get the path to artisan which is **/home/user/Desktop/blog**

Then you'll use this:

```
* * * * * php /home/user/Desktop/blog/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Artisan is located in your project directory. For instance, my crontab shows something like this:

```
 *  *  *  *  *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/projectfolder/artisan command
```

Answer (score -1):

On linux systems: 
Using terminal > Go to project folder-> run `pwd`.The path you should get is the absolute path to your project.

On Windows, I think you need to run `cd`